# Result set to ArrayList and display in JLabel

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans-8

How can i get rid of this error, the output is correct but i still get the error of "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:8". I try to output the result of query into JLabel.

```
private void PosName(){
    try{
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Position";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        ArrayList<String> pos = new ArrayList<>();

        while(rs.next()){
            pos.add(rs.getString("PositionName"));
        }
        String[] positionname = new String[pos.size()];
        positionname = pos.toArray(positionname);

        int v = 50;
        for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++){ 
               JLabel labels1 = new JLabel();
               labels1.setBounds(50,v,80,20);
               labels1.setText(positionname[i]);
               v+=40;
                jPanel3.add(labels1);     
        }
       jPanel3.repaint(); 
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

the output is :

[image]

please help me to solve this problem

Comment: use `for(int i = 0; i < positionname.length; i++){ ` instead

Comment: It looks like your array has only 8 elements, but you are looping through 100 elements. Did you mean to do `for(int i = 0; i < positionname.length; i++)` ?

Comment: @YCF_L and then still get out of bounds exception, because you used `<=` instead of `<`

Comment: yes this is correct @CoderinoJavarino sorry